# Conditional Statement Block of Java Code Not Working

Tags: java, arrays, conditional-statements, output

Why is the if the conditional block of this code NOT working? This method gets called in another method with inputs but the code doesn't give the correct output. It appears the "If" part of the conditional statement does not get executed.

```
private static String replace(String x, String y, String phrase)
{
    StringBuilder sample = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (String temp : phrase.split(" ")) 
    {
        if(temp == x) 
        {
            sample.append(y+" ");
        }else {
            sample.append(temp + " ");
        }
    }

    return sample.toString();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What is input to this method?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/64388167/4762502 should answer you question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hard to tell without knowing the inputs but one of the most obvious errors in the code above is the equality operator in the 'if' statement.

To compare strings in java, use equals method like this - `temp.equals(x)`.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: sure, no problem.